# How to stop function with interval if div count exceeds 5 in jQuery?

Tags: jquery

Even when there are 5+ divs on screen it keeps going, any way to fix this?

```
if ($('div').length > 5) {
  // Do nothing
} else {
  window.setInterval(function(){
    $(document).ready(function() {
      $('body').append('<div>' + (Math.floor(Math.random() * 9) + 0) + '</div>');
    });
  }, 1000);
}
```

Comment: Think about when you are checking the number of div's.  You'll want to learn to use a loop or maybe recursion.  Also, document.ready is a wrapper.  It shouldn't be in the middle of your function.

Comment: I tried doing a for loop with the condition (i = 0; i < 5; i++) but it doesn't work.

Comment: It's `var i = 0`.  Maybe that's the problem?  What are you ultimately trying to do?

Comment: This is a section of code in a matrix style background I'm trying to create. Adding the var doesn't help.

Comment: Add that code to your question too.  It's ok to show a few attempts.  So you just need to add 5 div's to the body?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It sounds like what you want is to clear the interval timer when 5 are created so you would need to check again inside the interval timer code also

Something like:

```
var timer= window.setInterval(function(){
    if ($('div').length > 5){
       clearInterval(timer)
    }else{
        $('body').append('<div>' + (Math.floor(Math.random() * 9) + 0) + '</div>');
    }     

  }, 1000);
```

Comment: you could also remove the outer if/else completely. The result would be the same and it would look a little cleaner imo